# login created token, but still get an error react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react native application. And an login service call.

And if I trigger the login service call the token has been created. But I still get an login failed error. So this is the service call:

```
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/user/token/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);

        if (response.ok) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", data.access);

            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Error(data.detail);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Login failed");
    }
};
```

And in the console I see that the token has created:

```
 Object {
  "token": "a608aa4c5c584f288c6afce37ef963985ec64f1c",
}
```

Question: how to proper login?

Comment: Add `console.log(error)` under `catch (error)` and see what is the actual error

Comment: @Konrad. I get this as output [AsyncStorage] Passing null/undefined as value is not supported. If you want to remove value, Use .removeItem method instead.
Passed value: undefined
Passed key: Token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` object doesn't have an "`access`" field, you just logged it in the console and it only shows a "`token`" field (from what you provide in your post).

And you are passing `data.access` as the value for "`Token`" when calling `AsyncStorage.setItem`.

Obviously that is not possible and you probably meant to pass `data.token` instead.

Comment: Doesn't have `data.detail` as well

Comment: @mightycodeNewton as someone else suggested: do go over errors (never ignore them), since you get "passing null/undefined" my first reflex would have been to look at which value i'm passing (in this case data.access) then verify if access exists on data or not by logging it in the console :)